# React js mulitple components returned by api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi all and happy new year,

I have done some simple applications in React-JS. However now I'm build a little more complex app and I just want to know if I'm heading in the right direction. I didn't find any question like this so here goes:

In the admin section a web-editor can populate the page with 3 different modules so far. Meaning my API can return something like this:

```
{
  "component_name": 'x',
  "title": "Hello world",
  "body": "Nice to see you"
},
{
  "component_name": 'y',
  "image": "http://localhost/image.png",
  "title": "my fancy image"
},
{
  "component_name": 'z',
  "whatever": "test",
  "someting": "test"
}
```

Or something like this

```
{
  "component_name": 'x',
  "title": "Hello world",
  "body": "Nice to see you"
},
{
  "component_name": 'x',
  "title": "Hello again",
  "body": "Nice to see you again"
},
{
  "component_name": 'y',
  "image": "http://localhost/image.png",
  "title": "my fancy image"
}
```

Since I don't know what components will be return I wrote a switch-statement. As I stated earlier I didn't find any question like this and I just want to know if this is the correct way? Or am I missing something fundamentally here?

```
const { components } = this.state;
let xComponent = null;
components.map((item, index) => {

        switch (item.component_name) {
            case 'x':
                xComponent = <xComponent title={item.title} text={item.text} />
                break;
            default:

        }
    });
    return(
        xComponent
    )
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Is something not working or are you asking for feedback?

Comment: @azium I'm asking for feedback

Comment: @DipenDedania I just want a push in the right direction. Is the switch-statement a proper way of display components?

Comment: @henrik123 - I'm still not sure that I got your point correctly, but I think in ideal scenarios, you don't need switch statements in ReactJS for conditional rendering of components.

Comment: Checkout this - https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: can you please provide how to use from xComponent when you return it?
<xComponent /> or {someFunction()} in your render?

Comment: Also note xComponent is not a valid name for custom component since all custom components should start with uppercase letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you're saying. You want to build page components based on the admin content manager. I went down that road before and it works quite well. If your api returns the data, you can render it just as you described. I wrote a more concrete example below.

```
class Page extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pageComponents: [{
        "type": 'wysiwyg',
        "props": {
          "title": "Hello world",
          "body": "Nice to see you",
        },
      }, {
        "type": 'video',
        "props": {
          "title": "Hello again",
          "body": "Nice to see you again",
        },
      }, {
        "type": 'image',
        "props": {
          "image": "http://localhost/image.png",
          "title": "my fancy image",
        },
      }],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.pageComponents.map((item, i) => {
      switch (item.type) {
        case 'wysiwyg':
          return <Wysiwyg key={i} {...item.props} />
          break;
        case 'video':
          return <Video key={i} {...item.props} />
          break;
        case 'image':
          return <Image key={i} {...item.props} />
          break;
        default:
          return null;
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: thank you. Thats exactly want I meant and I'll go with this solution then